Sending Data from MAX78000FTHR Microcontroller to NodeMCU via UART Protocol
I'm currently working on a project where I need to send data from a MAX78000FTHR microcontroller to a NodeMCU (ESP8266) using the UART protocol. I've set up both devices and would like to establish a reliable communication channel between them.
Connections:

MAX78000FTHR TX (Transmitter) → NodeMCU RX (Receiver)
MAX78000FTHR RX (Receiver) → NodeMCU TX (Transmitter)
Common Ground: Connect the ground (GND) pins of both devices together.

NodeMCU Code:
Here’s the code for the NodeMCU to receive the data:
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);  // Initialize UART at 9600 baud rate
    Serial.println("Ready to receive data...");
}

void loop() {
    if (Serial.available()) {
        int incomingData = Serial.read();  // Read the incoming data
        Serial.print("Received: ");
        Serial.println(incomingData);        // Print the received data
    }
}

I need the sender code for the MAX78000FTHR microcontroller along with the necessary connections to send data to a NodeMCU via UART protocol.
I attempted to establish UART communication between the MAX78000FTHR microcontroller and a NodeMCU by wiring the TX and RX pins correctly. I expected the data sent from the MAX78000FTHR to be received and printed by the NodeMCU. However, the NodeMCU is not displaying the expected data, indicating a possible issue in the max78000fthr code or connections.`

It seems that your code would echo the data back out on the same UART it received it on. Where is it supposed to "display" it?

UART is a communications interface, not a protocol.  You are using a single default serial port normally connected to the development host for debug output via USB.  Likely you need to use a second, different port for the incoming data? UART connection are normally point-to-point, not a bus or network with multiple connected devices.  What data are you sending from the MAX78000FTHR?  You are reading binary data, but outputting as if it were text - which may be nonsense.

The ESP8266 has two UARTs the one you are connecting to the MAX78000FTHR should not be the same as the one you are using for the debug communications.  You have not indicated which you have wired, but the code is clearly reading from the same one as used for debug. Also NodeMCU refers to Lua firmware for Espressif devices, not the hardware.  You appear to be using the Arduino C++ framework, not NodeMCU.  You are perhaps no alone in that misapprehension.

Googling around https://www.robmiles.com/journal/2021/1/29/using-the-second-serial-port-on-the-esp8266 suggests that the second UART on ESP8266 is transmit only.  As such you must connect Serial port as you have but you cannot then use it as a debug interface.  I would suggest that the hardware is rather inadequate for you application.  Or at least it would be very hard to debug and develop on.
